# How to change the effect of focusing on an NSTextField on OSX

Tags: macos, cocoa, focus, nstextfield

In CSS, you can change the effect of focusing on something using:

```
.myelement:focus { ... }
```

While in Cocoa, the text fields always have an ugly blue glow. How do I change the effect of focusing on an NSTextField (or not have it do anything at all)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Cocoa equivalent of the command above would be:

```
[[textField window] makeFirstResponder:textField];
```

As to changing the appearance, are you asking how to change it for all controls in all applications ("globally") or just for a text field in your own app? There's no API for a global change, so system hacks are your only avenue. Good luck.

For controls you own (those that belong to your own application), you can set the focus ring type in Interface Builder or by code at runtime like this:

```
[textField setFocusRingType:NSFocusRingTypeNone]; 
// (or NSFocusRingTypeDefault or NSFocusRingTypeExterior)
```

Comment: I'm not seeing where one can set `NSFocusRingTypeNone` in Interface Builder. Other than that, your answer helped me.

Comment: @AdamJohns Under the Attributes panel, the last section is titled "View". The Focus Ring setting control is a popup button. Choose "None".

Comment: I noticed this seems to not work for `NSSecureTextField`. Have you experienced that issue also?

Comment: @AdamJohns I've never tried it. The secure text firld is treated differently for obvious reasons but I can't imagine the focus ring setting being locked down for security reasons. Maybe a good candidate for filing a radar.

Comment: I have confirmed that programmatically setting focus ring type on an `NSSecureTextField` appears to work fine. Only setting the type in Interface Builder seems to not work. FYI for future readers.